# Merging raster data with certain condition

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, merge, conditional

I am doing a project and one demand is to create single raster by merging two rasters (Raster U and Raster R) into one (raster N) and only if conditions are met.

The picture below shows those conditions.

Can someone instruct me how to do this in QGIS?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Since QGIS 3.22 it is quite simple using a nested `if` in the Raster Calculator

If either of them are 0, use 0, else if RasterU is greater than or equal to RasterR use RasterR, else use RasterU

```sql
if("RasterU@1" = 0 or "RasterR@1" = 0, 0, if("RasterU@1" >= "RasterR@1", "RasterR@1", "RasterU@1"))
```